# ASP.NET MVC, Loading forms via PartialViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, partialviews

I am developing an application using ASP.Net MVC and jQuery. Depending on users action, I load partial views into the page using jQuery's $.ajax method.

The problem, I am experiencing, is related to a particular partial view that contains a form, in which the client side validation is enabled. It does seem like the JavaScript code generated in this partial view is not being executed, hence the client validation is not working.

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

Thanks!

Zen

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put all scripts contained in this partial into a separate function. Then in the `success` callback of you AJAX request simply call this function: it should attach validation to the newly modified DOM.

Comment: Hey Darin, JS validation code is generated on runtime. Therefore, I can not put it in a separate function.